GeoDjango automatically transforming my coordinates
I have an API using GeoDjango and PostGIS. Every time I try to add a post with a point it gets saved as another point around 10,000 times less than the values I entered for both latitude and longitude.
I am trying to use WSG84 everywhere and I do not have to make any transforms to another system.
The model I am trying to add to:
class Job(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    haul_from = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    haul_to = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True)
    job_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

The form:
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('job_name', 'description', 'haul_from')

The serializer:
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('id', 'job_name', 'created_by', 'created_at_formatted', 'description', 'haul_from', 'haul_to', 'job_active')

The api:
@api_view(['POST'])
def job_create(request):
    form = JobForm(request.data)
    print(request.data)
    if (request.user.company is None):
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Please join or create a company'})

    if form.is_valid():
        job = form.save(commit=False)
        job.created_by = request.user.company
        job.save()

        serializer = JobSerializer(job)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Something went wrong'})

If I input this into my post request:
Point(45.87159732871114 -66.5314351925612)

I receive this as what is saved into the database:
"SRID=4326;POINT (0.0004120715698736 -0.0005976620510765)"

I believe I have the PostGIS extension properly installed to my database, as well.

Looking at the values, it looks like your data is (wrongly) assumed to be in 3857 and it is first reprojecting it to 4326. The output is a point with 45/66 meters away form 0;0. select st_asText(st_transform(ST_GeomFromEWKT('srid=3857;point(45.87159732871114 -66.5314351925612)'),4326)); --> POINT(0.000412071569874 -0.000597662051068)

The issue was that the data from json from the http requests are not in float format. The geos Point object requires float values. All I had to do was take the values from the json request and cast them:
@api_view(['POST'])
def job_create(request):
form = JobForm(request.data)
lat = request.data['lat']
lon = request.data['lon']
if (request.user.company is None):
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Please join or create a company'})

if form.is_valid():
    job = form.save(commit=False)
    job.created_by = request.user.company
    job.haul_from = Point(float(lat), float(lon))
    job.save()

    serializer = JobSerializer(job)

    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

else:
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Something went wrong'})


No, you are creating a new point (which, by the way, should be expressed as longitude first, then latitude) in the proper CRS, while the original code is reprojecting the point from 3857 to 4326. The fix you are observing has nothing to do with using floats but rather because it skips the (faulty) reprojection.
